# Logging to stdout vs logging to file from multiple processes simultaneously

Tags: python, macos, operating-system, stdout

I have a process (in python) which spawns multiple processes.
They all log to stdout and also to a file.

When I run the code (added bellow), all the logs to stdout get scrambled, as I actually thought would happen.

But, the log file looks amazingly neat and clean.
So I then tried redirecting stdout to a file, and that file was also neat and clean.
I've also tried different log sizes, but all yielded the same result.

So I guess I'm asking what exactly is happening here.
I've read a bit about stream buffering, but I'm not sure it's related (though maybe I'm wrong :))

It looks like writing to a file is atomic, but it isn't for stdout, which seems a bit strange to me.

Running python3.7 on MacOS:

```py
import multiprocessing
import logging.config

config = {
    "version": 1,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(threadName)s %(module)s(%(lineno)d): %(message)s"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "formatter": "default",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        },
        "file": {
            "formatter": "default",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "/tmp/test.log"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "my_logger": {
            "handlers": ["console", "file"],
            "level": "DEBUG"
        }
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(config)

def foo(char):
    my_logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
    import os, time
    msg = f'{os.getpid()}' + (char * 2400)
    s=time.time()
    while 1:
        my_logger.info(msg)
        if time.time() - s > 5:
            break

ps = [multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(chr(i+64),)) for i in range(10)]
for p in ps:
    p.start()
```

Comment: I'm going to assume (without thoroughly reading the code), that this is race conditions. While accessing files - only one can access it at time. But stdout can be access by anything at any point of time. However, I'd have to check to make sure this is indeed the case why it happens

Comment: But is that the case? Can a file only be accessed by one process at a time? Are the other ones blocking during that time?
Is this os specific?

Comment: Writing to a file cannot be atomic but it is probably spinlock or mutex protected. It means the first process/thread to make a system call to write to a file is probably the first to atomically lock the mutex and the next thread have to wait. The OS simply puts the file operation on a queue and waits for a DMA device to handle it. I don't know for stdout.